# Features to build windows forms?

Tags: forms

I have a windows forms application and need to launch it in the market. I need to ask that what are the last minute changes that need to be added or precautions that are to be carried out before taking my application to the market. I want to know the industry standards which need to be followed so that my application achieves success.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion:

**Technical:**

- Authenticode-sign your application
- Have a single-file setup executable that installs the app as well as *all* prerequisites.
- Sign your setup, too

**"Marketing":**

- Have an idea to whom to sell
- Have a marketing budget
- Have a website
- Do SEO
- Maybe do online advertisement
- Listen to your customers
- Constantly improve your product and support

On the other hand, likely you should have done some research *before* developing your application to ensure whether there is a need at all, not *after* finishing the development.

The SEO guys at Google usually tell you "If you have great content/applications for your customers, success will come automatically", but I really doubt that. Having great connections to popular editors and blogger will help you, depending on your product, a lot to get visibility ;-)